# post isset($_POST['next'] is not set after submit /refresh page. Need to be press twice for it to be set how to fix?

Tags: php, html

```
<script>
function refreshPage()
{
  document.forms[0].submit();
}    
</script>

<?php
       
 foreach($values as $value)
  {
  ?>
   <input type = "checkbox" name = "food[]" value = "<?php echo($value['dinner']);?>"  
     <?php if(isset($_POST['food'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > // note this is still part of 
      input

  <?php 
       } 
    ?>


<button name = "pass" onClick = "refreshPage()">refresh</button>

<?php 

     if(isset($_POST['pass'])
    {    
        // do a lot more stuff but I have this for temp info
        echo("hello");
        // I am printing all the check box values in here I do not
        // have the code for it yet but I think ik how to do it
        // but since i do not have code for it now it is just empty
    }
?>
```

hi so everytime I click on the button refresh. the isset($_POST['pass']) does not work. I have to click on it a second for it to be set which would then print the  hello and table of check items part.

I want it so that if you click on it once it will print the hello. Not twice. How do i fix my code? FYI I know you could do isset($_POST['food']) for it to work. But that will break other parts of my code.

I need the button to set the isset($_POST['pass']) to be True (after one click) after I press the refresh button one time.

Comment: Couple things, you have a syntax error on `if(isset($_POST['pass'])` and secondly, there are no form tags. I assume you have form tags and your copy/paste was bad on that other line mentioned? And, why have a function submit the form when the natural action of a form is to submit? Presumably the `refreshPage()` does more "stuff" before it submits?